# How do I prevent apps from getting installed onto my Pixel?

Tags: installation

I'd like to prevent any apps from being installed on my Pixel.

I tried this with Google Family Link, but you can install apps rated E.

I also tried this with AppBlock, but I can install apps from play.google.com from my computer.

I'd like the primary user on this phone to no longer be able to install apps at all.

An acceptable solution would be to password protect installing new apps, so that someone with the password could install apps.

Comment: For enterprise usage you can white-list apps that are the only one allowed to be installed via PlayStore. This seems to be include in the "G Suite Basic" from Google which costs about 5€ per month. See https://support.google.com/a/answer/6328701?hl=en